# Every thing is true but fonts doesn't display

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I do some changes for website like:
More Secure, PageSpeed and etc

Every thing is true but fonts doesn't display!!!!

this is Url with Bad Display:
http://wellan.ir/index.php/ir/

another wonder still is here, in Url:
http://wellan.ir/index.php/en/
Font Displays truely!

I Check Css, Font-face, js & etc
No thing is wrong!

Any Suggestion?

please, see this image too:
[Link 1](http://tinypic.com/r/35lgl92/8) OR [Link 2](http://8pic.ir/images/pv62eprxixpoknrpe7y9.jpg)

Comment: You have a folder called index.php?

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/3mkhlf39y/font.jpg

Comment: @JamesDonnelly — No. PHP lets you put path parts after the PHP filename.

Comment: @Quentin interesting. I never knew that!

Comment: Hi James Donnelly

"You have a folder called index.php?"

No, There is only 1 php file, I use Joomla 3.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Sulthan Allaudeen, Finally I find problem and its solution.

Solution is here, I add this to .htaccess

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://wellan.ir"

for multiple domain solution, see:

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)